# Observing heart rate data in Health Connect

Tags: android, healthconnect

I've noticed that FitBit updates Health Connect once a minute with the latest heart rate read. I was wondering if there is a way to subscribe to those updates via the new Health Connect API. The documentation around how to approach the solution is really fuzzy, and the [Changes Sync API](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/health-connect/data-and-data-types/differential-changes-api) appears to be a dead link. I would prefer not to use the WorkManager, but rather just send Health Connect a Callback that would trigger if the changes to a vital sign are detected. I think that would be a better approach then polling the API every minute to see if there is something new.

What are the best practices around this?

Thank you,

I was looking to find an API on [Sync Data](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/common-workflows/sync-data) Page and have a hard time finding the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the broken link. I've submitted a correction for this,  which will point to: https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/data-and-data-types/differential-changes-api

The Changes Sync API is a pull-based API, so you need to call `getChanges()` each time you want to get the latest data.

From your description, it sounds like you are after a push-based API, which unfortunately isn't available in Health Connect at this time.